# Although ouput is coming on my Codeblocks IDe submission of the code tells No output

Tags: c++

So here is a c++ program which finds maximum distance between same pair of integer. So for a array [2,9,3,2,4,5,2] it ouputs 6 because highest distance between any pair of integer (here it's 2) is 6-0. But when i am submitting it to a online editor (hackerearth) in a programming contest it tells me my output is 0 where in my Codeblocks IDE i am getting the expected output. What is going wrong here ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

bool inArr(int i,int Arr[],int size)
 {
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
         if(i==Arr[i])
         {
            return true;
         }
    }
   return false;
}

 int maxy(int i,int j,int Arr[],int size)
 {
    for(int k=size-1;k>j;k--)
    {
        if(Arr[k]==i)
        {
            return k-j;
        }

  }
  return 0;

}



int main()
{
int n;
int j=0;
int A[n];
cin >> n ;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin >> A[i];
}
int temp[n];
int maxArr[n];
int k=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(inArr(A[i],temp,n)==false)
    {
        temp[j]=A[i];
        j++;
        int maxNum=maxy(A[i],i,A,n);
        maxArr[k]=maxNum;
        k++;


    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
int currMax=maxArr[0];
for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
{
    int num=maxArr[i];
    if(num>currMax)
    {
        currMax=maxArr[i];
    }
}
cout << currMax;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have not understood what pairs are considered.

Comment: In any case your program is invalid at least because the dimension of the array A is indeterminate.

Comment: The maximum index of 2 given in my array is 6 because index 6-index 0=6. But for the pair of other 2 (if you consider 1st 2 and 4th 2 it is 4-0). So the task is to find the maximum distance of any integer in the given array. Here no maximum distance between other integer of same type is not possible because other number appears only once.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow ,, i have given the length of my array A as n in the starting lines. So it has dimension. Isn't it ?

Comment: And what is the value of n?:)

Comment: `int n = ?; int A[n]; cin >> n ;` so an array of???

Comment: Oww...It is given. But i have created the array before that :(. Thank you. I found the mistake :)

Comment: Please post the comment in the answer section so i can upvote.. Thanks :)

Comment: @Nazmus Salehin I do not see any sense in this call of inArr  if(inArr(A[i],temp,n)==false) At least the array temp is not initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are creating an array of a garbage value:

```
int n; // n has a garbage value
int A[n]; // creating of array of ?? element?
cin >> n; // this should be before declaring the array:

int n;
cin >> n ; 
int j=0;
int A[n];
```

Comment: I understood. Thanks :)

Comment: @NazmusSalehin: Welcome and that sounds great for that it works for you!